# Is there a way I can make loop cuts of multiple (patterned) widths?

Tags: mesh

I want to be able to make a loop cuts like this:

[image: Patterned "loop cuts"]

In this example, I just approximated the width between cuts, but I would really like to be exact.

I'm planning on modelling a Ka-Bar knife and I was planning on using this for the handle as shown here:

[image: Ka-Bar]

Obviously this image/diagram thing is a slight oversimplification of what I'm actually trying to do (I'll need an additional, smaller width, C, between A and B so I can scale A up or B down on the Y- and Z-axes in order to get the the little grooves), but for the purpose of my question, I think this simplification is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the bvevel tool can do the job ?

1: Use the Loop Cut tool to create the required number of divisions.

[image]

2: With these new loop cuts selected use the Bevel tool to give these loop cuts the desired width.

[image]